# Unauthorized 401 on calling scan URL CopyLeaks API

Tags: postman, unauthorized, plagiarism-detection, copyleaks-api

I am trying to call an api of copyleaks using Postman
`https://api.copyleaks.com/v3/scans/submit/url/my-special-id`
but I am getting this error

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7235#section-3.1",
    "title": "Unauthorized",
    "status": 401,
    "traceId": "00-65af4c471c39e69a5ee1a561f3a45e3b-462c61c6f42e1771-00"
}
```

I have provided bearer token in authorization which is get from this api of copyleaks `https://id.copyleaks.com/v3/account/login/api`  which is working fine.

The body I am passing in for  `https://api.copyleaks.com/v3/scans/submit/url/my-special-id` is

```
{
    "url" : "https://edition.cnn.com/",
    "properties" : {
      "sandbox: : true,
      "webhooks" : {
        "status" : "https://enqfhwydhpa6b.x.pipedream.net/%7BSTATUS%7D/my-special-id"
       }
     }
}
```

The refrence I took from the video given on Copyleaks offical site [this video](https://vimeo.com/688756505),  the webhook url I take from requestbin to test the result if completed . .plz help!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: The question missing full explanation of your request. Please specify: HTTP method, URL, headers and body was sent. Remember to hide sensitive data like Authorization tokens

Comment: Without having all the information, it seems like you forgot to add the header `Authorization: Bearer <Your-Login-Token>` or your login token is wrong.

Comment: @No1Lives4Ever my HTTP method is PUT , url is https://api.copyleaks.com/v3/scans/submit/url/my-special-id
headers are content-type : application/json
Authorization : "Bearer {Token}"
And body I have mentioned in Question

and no my login token is not wrong